# Closing a session with unacknowledged INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE messages

Tags: activemq-classic

If a session with consumers with pending INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE messages is closed, what occurs?  Will the unacknowledged messages be resent when new consumers come online?  Will previously acknowledged INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE messages be resent?

My expectation is that the unacked messages will be resent and the acked messages will not, but I just wanted to make sure that is the contract and the expected behavior.  I am using 5.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages that have been dispatched to the consumer but are not acknowledged will be re-dispatched to another consumer once the original consumer they were dispatched to goes offline.